# excel attachment in webpage cannot read in ipad safari but it can in all other browsers

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
header("Pragma: public"); 
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private", false); 
header("Content-Type: application/force-download; name=\"" . $filename . "\" format=attachment;");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $filename . "\"");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ". filesize($filename));
```

This is my code.
indeed I have also tried to change some of the header line by searching relevant posts in stackflow but also fail.
plz help .

Comment: is associated the type of file in safari, needs safaria any plugin?

Comment: I try using another webpage and download another excel, it succeed.